# TypeError: source.subscribe is not a function in app.component / Ionic 5

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

In my app. I have a side menu where you can see the name of the user and profile, if you click a button, it takes you to the profile page where I can update the info. I am saving the user info in a user service, and I am having a hard time passing the user info into the app.component so that I can populate the side menu. I am trying to use observables. Apparently, the problem is with the logged.subscribe function.

My AuthService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private _userIsAuthenticated = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor() { }

  get userIsAuthenticated(){
    return this._userIsAuthenticated.asObservable;
  }

  login(){
    this._userIsAuthenticated.next(true);
  }

  logout(){
    this._userIsAuthenticated.next(false);
  }

}
```

My UserService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { take, map, tap, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { User } from '../model/user.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  private _loggedUser = new BehaviorSubject<User>(
    new User(null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
  );

  constructor() { }

  get loggedUser(){
    return this._loggedUser.asObservable;
  }

  setUser(sentUser: User){
    this._loggedUser.next(sentUser);
  }

  rmUser(){
    this._loggedUser.next(new User(null, null, null, null, null, null, null));
  }
}
```

This is my app.component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
import { UserService } from './services/user.service';
import { User } from './model/user.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private logged: Observable<boolean>;
  private user: User;

  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private router: Router,
    private menuCtrl: MenuController,
    private as: AuthService,
    private us: UserService,
  ) {
    this.logged = this.as.userIsAuthenticated();
    this.initializeApp();
    this.setUser();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  private setUser(){
    // console.log(this.logged.subscribe);
    this.logged.subscribe(v => {      
      if (v) {
        this.us.loggedUser().subscribe(user => {
          this.user = user;
        })
      }
    })
  }

  logout(){
    this.menuCtrl.close();
    this.as.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }

  profile(){
    this.menuCtrl.close();
    this.router.navigate(['/user/perfil']);
  }

  profilePro(){
    this.menuCtrl.close();
    this.router.navigate(['profesional/perfil']);
  }
}
```

The app wont compile, and i get this error

```
TypeError: source.subscribe is not a function
at Observable._subscribe (Observable.js:76)
at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:27)
at AppComponent.setUser (app.component.ts:45)
at new AppComponent (app.component.ts:33)
at NodeInjectorFactory.AppComponent_Factory [as factory] (ɵfac.js? [sm]:1)
at getNodeInjectable (core.js:4029)
at instantiateRootComponent (core.js:7826)
at createRootComponent (core.js:18375)
at ComponentFactory$1.create (core.js:22191)
at ApplicationRef.bootstrap (core.js:28319)
```

I have been reading around and it seems I have setup everything correctly. Any help or any tips to ompimizea and better the code in general, would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you defined `loggedUser()` as a [*getter*](https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/typescript-getters-setters/) :

```
get loggedUser(){
  return this._loggedUser.asObservable;
}
```

You should initialize your `logged` property like this:

```
this.logged = this.as.userIsAuthenticated; // not like userIsAuthenticated()
```

Please notice that now the error message (*source.subscribe is not a function*) make more sense, since it's telling you that the source is not actually a function and it shouldn't be called using `()`.

Comment: Thanks @sebaferreras, when I remove the (), the app wont compile and I get this error. TS2740: Type '() => Oservable<boolean>' is missing the following properties from type  'Oservable<boolean>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more...

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. @sebaferreras was right I needed to initialize

```
this.logged = this.as.userIsAuthenticated; // not like userIsAuthenticated();
```

But Also I was missing the "()" in my Service

```
return this._loggedUser.asObservable(); // it was missing the () at the end
```

Finally i had to remove the () from all the subscriptions like

```
this.us.loggedUser.subscribe(...); // instead of this.us.loggedUser().subscribe(...);
```

I hope this helps someone else having the same rookie mistake as me :D